# Rightsignature API is always returning 'Invalid OAuth Request'

Tags: php, api, oauth

I have created API keys after created an account with rightsignature. I downloaded the PHP rightsignature library from this [RS-PHP-Embedded-Sample](https://github.com/rightsignature/RS-PHP-Embedded-Sample) - 
After analysis the library, I just created a sample file and written the below code for testing.

```
<?php
require_once("config/common.inc.php");    

$rightsignature->getRequestToken();

$rightsignature->getAccessToken();
```

But I'm always getting `getAccessToken()` method response as '**Invalid OAuth Request**' even thought I'm using valid `oAuth Customer Key`, `oAuth Customer Secret keys`. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. Please help me to resolve this issue.

we can find some other PHP libraries related to rightsignature on this url - [api_documentation_php](https://rightsignature.com/apidocs/api_documentation_php)

But nothing helped me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?